# Managed Service Account does not have enough permissions while adding ObjectAcessControl

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

Trying to add object control access on deployment-manager:

```
- type: storage.v1.objectAccessControl
  name: url-access
  properties:
    role: READER
    bucket: "bucket"
    object: "object"
    entity: "email"
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.deployment-manager.deployments.update) Error in Operation [operation-1574856490078-59852d9a9d256-4d665591-d57c3ea1]: errors:
- code: RESOURCE_ERROR
  location: /deployments/.../resources/user-access
  message: '{
    "ResourceType": "storage.v1.objectAccessControl",
    "ResourceErrorCode": "403",
    "ResourceErrorMessage": {
        "code": 403,
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "message": "MANAGED_SA@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to bucket/file.",
                "reason": "forbidden"
            }
        ],
        "message": "MANAGED_SA@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to bucket/file.",
        "statusMessage": "Forbidden",
        "requestPath": "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucket/o/file/acl",
        "httpMethod": "POST",
        "suggestion": "Consider granting permissions to MANAGED_SA@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com"
    }
}'
```

Weird fact: the MANAGED-SA per default has Editor access on project. Even put Owner Access, I still got this message

Comment: having same issue but the service account in my case created randomly so I cannot give permission because with next trigger another random account is being created. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the role for service account `MANAGED_SA@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com: "Storage Object Admin". Viewer was not enough

Comment: yeah, was just a permission thing